# boost::array not compiling on VS 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, boost

Sorry this is probably a stupid question, as I couldn't find anything at all on google on the subject. Anyways I'm trying to compile some source code, that uses boost::array with visual studio 2005, as a Win32 console application (not clr), however for some reason that escapes me Visual Studio still considers the word ***array*** a keyword, so it chokes on all the boost::array<>'s in the code with errors like this:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'array' : is not a member of 'boost'
d:\projects\libraries\boost_1_36_0-1\boost_1_36_0\boost\asio\buffer.hpp 809
```

I'm quite sure there is something terribly stupid and probably obvious I'm missing as no one in the world seems to have this problem (according to Google's results I found)

Comment: 'array' is merely recognized by the syntax highlighter, so I don't think the compiler has a preconceived notion of arrays outside of /clr projects. Strange that asio's buffer should fail to find the array type, it includes boost/array.hpp. Do you have another array type in the global scope?

Comment: Not that I can think of, which is the whole issue, if I compile with /Za (no language extensions) it recognizes boost::array<> ok, but fails in other parts. So it's really really weird :/

Comment: If you right click on 'array' and choose "Go to Definition" or "Go to Declaration" does it take you somewhere that might give a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple program compiled and worked perfectly in my VC++ 2005:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int
main()
{
     const int size = 3;
     boost::array<double,size> myArray;
     myArray[0] = 23.43f;
     myArray[1] = 24.00f;
     myArray[2] = 23.50f;
     double sum = 0.0;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i) 
     {
         sum += myArray[i];
     }
     std::cout << "sum=" << sum << '\n';
     return 0;
}
```

Could you post a small code snippet that fails?

Comment: This actually didn't compile :/ So I downloaded Boost again, and now it does. Somehow my boost distribution was broken.